# What is $(X/2 + Y/2)/ (X + Y)$? A conjecture?

Tags: arithmetic

I am new to mathematics. When I was doing course work on fractions.
I learned something like follows

> $(2 + 5) / (4 + 10)$

learned a common pattern

> $(X/2 + Y/2)/ (X + Y)$      or     $(X + Y)/ (2(X + Y))$

I plugged in some number and tested, it seems to be right.

- To which field(number theory, arithmetic) this kind of question
  belongs to?
- Is this a conjecture? theorem?
- How could I proof such a simple equation hold util infinity?

Comment: Do you mean $(x/2 + y/2)/(x+y)$ (and $(2+5)/(4+10)$)? The parenthesis are important: they determine the order of operations!

Comment: Your parenthesing looks incorrect. Your question belongs to elementary arithmetic and is a simple consequence of associativity and distributivity of multiplication and division. Technically speaking it's a theorem, but a very "immediate" one. It holds for any numbers such that $X+Y\ne0$, and the expression simplifies to just $1/2$.

Comment: @Magdiragdag corrected

Comment: @YvesDaoust Can you elaborate "a simple consequence of associativity and distributivity of multiplication and division."

Comment: @user158: I did !

Comment: @YvesDaoust thanks

Comment: @user158 Your parenthesis are still incorrect in $2 + 5/4 + 10$ and in $(X+Y)/2(X+Y)$. The last one is evaluated left to right, but you mean $(X+Y)/(2(X+Y))$.

Comment: @Magdiragdag thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{\dfrac X2+\dfrac Y2}{X+Y}=\frac{\dfrac12(X+Y)}{X+Y}=\dfrac12\frac{X+Y}{X+Y}=\frac{X+Y}{2(X+Y)}=\frac12.$$

Justifications:

$$ab+ac=a(b+c),\\\frac ab\frac cd=\frac{ac}{bd}.$$